# Why do I need to replace the variables pt and tr?

Tags: python

```
pt = int(input('First Term: '))
rz = int(input('Ratio: '))
tr = pt
pc = 1
while pc <= 10:
    print('{}'.format(tr))
    tr += rz
    pc += 1
```

I can't understand why I  need to replace 'pt' with 'tr'. If I don't, my code doesn't work

Comment: Could you show us the other code which you claim is not working as expected?

Comment: Please make clear what the expected behaviour is, what the current (wrong) behaviour is and how they are different. 'it doesn't work' is unhelpful and the question cannot be answered in its current form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
pt = int(input('First Term: '))
rz = int(input('Ratio: '))
#here removed the variable tr
pc = 1
while pc <= 10:   
    print('{}'.format(pt))
    pt += rz
    pc += 1
```

Here I have just removed the variable tr. Both gives same output.

Output:

```
First Term: 2
Ratio: 4
2
6
10
14
18
22
26
30
34
38
```

Send feedback if your problem is not this or not solved.

Comment: wasn't working for me, I might have done somthing wrong, but thanks